# How to configure Django views and urls to render specific templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

When I bring up 127.0.0.1:8000, the current page that show up is `something.html` template.

I would need to make it appear index.html at first launch, then when I click on other parts,it should go to 127.0.0.1:8000/something.html (or 127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/something.html).

**What would be the structure to achieve this?**
I frequently get error message : `The current URL didn't match any of these.`

Currently, my structure is

```
project
     ---myapp
          ---admin.py
          ---models.py
          ---url.py
          ---views.py
     ---static
     ---templates
          ---myapp
             ---html files
     ---mysite
          ---settings.py
          --- url.py
```

under my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

under mysettings/url.py

```
   urlpatterns = [
        # Examples:
        url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
        url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ]
```

mysite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]


admin.site.site_header = 'Admin'
```

myapp/url.py

```
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #brings up something.html when we comment it out. No module found if included.
    #url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Include urls of your `myapp` app in `mysite/urls.py`

```python
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

]
```

Now, all urls, starting by `127.0.0.1:8000`, will check if there is a view that can handle the request. I recommend you to read this to understand how Django URL dispatcher works : [Django documentation - URL Dispatcher]  (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/).
2. Add new route in your `myapp.urls`:

```python
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^something$', views.something, name='something'),
    url(r'^posts$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
)
```

Now :
`127.0.0.1:8000/` will executed code of `views.home`
`127.0.0.1:8000/something` will executed code of `views.something`
`127.0.0.1:8000/posts` will executed code of `views.post_list`
Let's define these view now

3: Define the views in `myapp.views` :

```python
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    """
    Return home page
    """
    return render(request, 'myapp/home.html')

def something(request):
    """
    Return something page
    """
    return render(request, 'myapp/something.html')

def post_list(request):
    """
    Return something page
    """
    # do what you want
```

4. Add your templates in `myapp/templates/myapp/`. Add `home.html` and  `something.html`.

Now forget, the `.html

Comment: Thanks. This clarifies. However, when I visit 127.0.0.1:8000 after setting everything like this, something.html pops up on startup before home.html. Why is this?

Comment: 'module' object has no attribute 'home'

Comment: remove the line `url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),` from `mysite.urls.py` and use only `url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),`

Comment: That's the only line I'm using under mysite.urls.py

Comment: When I remove url(r'^$', views.home, name='home') from myapp.urls, something.html shows up. But when I place that line, it creates  
'module' object has no attribute 'home' msg.

Comment: add your views, your `mysite/urls`, and `myapp/urls.py` to your question please

Comment: Added in to the question @Louis Barranqueiro

Comment: you forget the view. But It can bug if you have to view on a same urls, and that is the case. you have `views.home` and `views.post_list` on  `r'^$'` url

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details about URL and how to reach views, check it out.

Comment: Good news mate. I recommend you to read carefully the Django documentation. All of this, is in it :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You create a `url` (with attached `view` to it).
2. In the `view` you render any html page you want.

If you use function based views your `'mysite.views.home'` may look like:

```
def home(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'path/to/index.html')
```

and so on.

It's the basics so I won't talk about this much. You can find a good tutorial about mapping urls to views [there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/).