# Why won't my django view use the template that I specified?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

When I look a the `companies_by_x` view in my browser it renders with the  `index.html` template and not the template I specified, which is `company_list.html` -- that template is specified for the `index` view. How can I get `companies_by_x` to use the `company_list.html` template? Each view has its own URL.  Thank you.

```
def companies_by_x(request):
    company_list = Company.objects.filter(locations__in=[1,2]).distinct()
    context = {'company_list':company_list}
    return render(request, 'companies/company_list.html', context)


def index(request):
    company_list = Company.objects.order_by('-id')[:5]
    context = {'company_list':company_list}
    return render(request, 'companies/index.html', context)
```

urls.py ---

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<company_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^companylist/$', views.companies_by_x, name='companies_by_x'),
]
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33766358/9038475)?

Comment: The problem is probably in your URLs. The `index` view is probably handling the requests you want to go to `companies_by_x`.

Comment: Please share your `urls.py`

Comment: Check your `urls.py`

Comment: urls.py added above

Comment: Your views and urls look ok to me. I would double check that you are running the code you think you are - save all files, restart server etc. You could also add some printing/logging to the views to make sure that the correct view is handling the request. You might also find the Django debug toolbar useful.